# Problem with Internal Boundaries in NDSolve / FEM using the If Function

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, finite-element-method

I'm still fairly new to Mathematica and am learning how to use NDSolve and FEM.

On youtube I found an interesting presentation done by Paritosh Mokhasi about [finite elements](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HkZ2KfTr8HY) that I'm trying to follow. When trying to implement an internal boundary shown in the presentation (~6:30 in the video), I run into an error. The code is working fine in Paritosh's presentation, is there a specific reason to why it isn't working for me:

```
c = If[x^2 + y^2 <= 1/4, {{10, 0}, {0, 10}}, {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}];
eqn = Div[-c.Grad[u[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] == 1;
Ω = Disk[];
d1 = DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, x >= 0];
sol = NDSolveValue[{eqn, d1}, u, {x, y} ∈ Ω]
```

As the copied code is fairly messy, here's a screenshot:
[image]

It has something to do with the If function. using a value instead of c works fine.

Comment: The basic problem is that `eqn` evaluates before `c` evaluates.

Comment: You might want to try using `Inactive[Grad]` and `Inactive[Div]` in your `eqn`.

Comment: Thanks @Silvia it works fine!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `Inactive[Grad]` and `Inactive[Div]` in `eqn` fixes the Problem:

```
c = If[x^2 + y^2 <= 1/4, {{10, 0}, {0, 10}}, {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}];
eqn = Inactive[Div][ -c.Inactive[Grad][u[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] == 1;
\[CapitalOmega] = Disk[];
d1 = DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, x >= 0];
sol = NDSolveValue[{eqn, d1}, u, {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega]]
```

more Information can also be found in the [FEM documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/SolvingPDEwithFEM.html)  - section "Partial Differential Equations with Variable Coefficients"